# Is it possible to disable browser refreshing in Codekit 2?

Tags: codekit

Does anyone know of a way to disable browser refreshing in Codekit 2? I’m enjoying the local server feature, but we have multiple people working on the site, and every time one person changes and saves a file we all get our pages refreshed. I'd like to temporarily disable it.

I know there are other ways for folks to access my site locally, but Codekit is what we're using for this right now.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Sorry, no – I ended up just using the non-codekit address for it.

Comment: How do you find the non-codekit address?

Comment: I was using MAMP and had set the domain as “local.sitename”. If you’re using MAMP try visiting the address shown in Server Name.

Comment: Wait, you used the MAMP domain on a different device? I was under the impression that you'd have to use the IP address of the device running MAMP to access the local site across a LAN

Comment: @HexLuthor Yeah, in my case when accessing it from multiple other Macs we used the MAMP domain and [edited the hosts file](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/). So if a co-worker on the same local network wanted to work on my local site without seeing the auto refresh *and I needed file watching on* we’d edit her hosts file to have it look to my IP for “local.sitename”.  

Unfortunately this isn’t an option on mobile devices that lack hosts file customization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pause file watching:

> Press command + option + control + / to toggle CodeKit's file-watching
>   on and off.

This stopped auto refreshing for me when I made a change. You can still use codekit's address and it won't refresh when you make a change if you have paused watching.

Comment: Thank you!!! I knew about this feature but rarely used it. And for whatever reason it never occurred to me that this is (obviously) what it would do.

Comment: Unfortunately this also prevents CodeKit from doing any compiling / preprocessing...

Comment: @HexLuthor True, true. In some cases this is where manually pressing CodeKit’s **Compile** button (while your file is selected) comes in handy. But obviously that’s a big hassle if you’re trying to quickly make a lot of changes.